# initial ssh login to 14.04 server from Linux Mint 17 always times out

Tags: ssh, timeout, ubuntu-14.04

Very strange one this. I have some EC2 nodes running standard 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I use Linux Mint 17 on my laptop, which is also based on 14.04. In my office (in West Cambridge) I can ssh in from my laptop, every time.

However when I try the same from home (BT Infinity, standard router, North Cambridge), the first login *always* times out. If I ctrl-c and try again it will work on the third time, pretty consistently, and will often work on the second time if I run in -vvv mode. After the first successful login I can logout and login no problem, but if I wait a few minutes the problem will reappear.

I can happily ssh in from a 11.04 box I have under the stairs, so it does seem to be something to do with 14.04, and presumably this chunk of the internet.

If I use "ssh -vvv" the last few lines are:

```
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

There doesn't seem to be anything out of the ordinary on the server logs: the only time I see an entry is after a successful connection, so it does appear to be client side, and of course the 11.04 box works every time.

Any insight would be much appreciated. It's something I can work around, but it's really irritating.

Comment: I have seen a similar problem caused by a stack which would use fragmentation for the first TCP segment which happened to be too large for the PMTU. In that particular case handling of fragmented packets was broken. Later connections worked because the stack had cached the PMTU and thus generated smaller TCP segments which did not need fragmentation. A packet capture would reveal if you are facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks - presumably you mean tcpdump? Any idea what kind of thing I'm looking for?

Comment: Any tool to perform a packet capture will do. I usually use tcpdump or wireshark depending on the circumstances. Using tcpdump from the command line to dump all possibly relevant packets to a file which I can later analyze with wireshark is a good workflow for me. What I look for in such dumps is the first time either end of the connection does something which is deviating from the standard. That's of course easier to look for if one knows the standard. Often the problem is that packets are being dropped by a misconfigured firewall, so look for packets that are apparently missing or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my BT HomeHub router. Switched to another router and my sshs work first time, every time. I suspect you're right at it was MTU related, but there are very few options to tweak that setting in the BT router.